# Looking for a solution to open folders with dynamically created buttons in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, dynamic

I'm looking for a solution to open folders with dynamically created buttons. Since I'm new to coding the solution i found so far is a bit wonky. Because im using a `Textbox` to get an actual `string` value which I can use.

```
public string MainDirPath = @"C:\....";
public string DirPath { get; set; }

public class Person
 {
  public string Name { get; set; }
 }

private void Btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
  Button Btn;
  Person pers;
  TextBox tb;
  StackPanel s;

  List<string> lstDirs = new List<string>(Directory.GetDirectories(MainDirPath));
  foreach (string Dir in lstDirs)
  {
   Btn = new Button();
   pers = new Person();
   tb = new TextBox();
   s = new StackPanel();

   pers.Name = Dir;
   tb.Text = Dir;
   Btn.Content = tb;
   Btn.Height = 200;
   Btn.Name = "Button_" + (++i).ToString();
   Btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Btn_Click);
   tb.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Tb_DoubleClick);

   s.Children.Add(Btn);
   StkPnl_MG.Children.Add(s);
   }
  }
void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 Button btn = sender as Button;
}
void Tb_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
 DirPath = tb.Text;
 lstBox.Items.Add(tb.Text);
}
```

I was using Google to find a better soulution, but I might not know the right therms to look for.

Comment: What do you mean "open folders", as in open an explorer at a specific path, or displaying the clicked folder in WPF(kinda like a self implemented explorer)?

Comment: Well i have a main folder with many folders in it and in these folders are many images. This app  should be able to create buttons based on the amount of folders in the main folder. And these buttons should have the name of the folder(and other informations) on it.And these button should open this folders by clicking on them, to display the images of these folders. I dindt include the image part of it.

Comment: Alright, when you say it should display the images of these folders  you mean in your app not in windows explorer right?

Comment: Yeah exactly in my app

Comment: You could try saving the button objects in a list and every time the directory changes(the folder they click into) just delete the buttons and re-make new ones and add them to the list. Alternatively you can just go through the list and change their text and callbacks

Comment: @SpleX Can you explain briefly and accurately what you need? I want to make a sample for you.

Comment: @james.lee I need something to assign each folder path to its button. So i get the folder path as value by clicking the button. Instead of double clicking in a textbox to assign the folder path to a variable in order to get this value.